# Prefect Multiple Database Connections

Tags: prefect

How does Prefect handle multiple database connections for flows or how does it delegate drivers and runtimes for connections to say; Oracle, SQL Server, and Snowflake?

If I have a single Prefect server on Kubernetes, does Docker handle all of this, or does the prefect server that hosts many flows that connect to many sources?

Comment: We're running a Kubernetes setup for our Prefect deployment and have a custom image built which runs different tasks.

Currently connecting to MSSQL database and a Postgres one as sources - have had to setup all dependencies on the image ran by the agent so things run smoothly (for all connectors)

We did a bit of R&D with my colleague and managed to get the following setup running and he wrote a great description of it:
https://infinitelambda.com/post/prefect-workflow-automation-azure-devops-aks/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Prefect does not connect to sources in the way that tools like Stitch or Fivetran do. Flows, which would be python scripts, are orchestrated using prefect on the infrastructure of your choice and from those scripts you are able to create connections and generally do whatever you want.